# Powershell: sort a dataset

Tags: sorting, powershell, dataset

In a powershell program I use a dataset for several uses.
One of these uses will benefit of a different sort order.

I tested this :

```
$array = $mydataset.tables[0].select("COL1 DESC")
```

But when I want to use $array, it is empty.

Question 1: how to sort a dataset into another dataset or an array ?
Question 2: how to do a multi-columns sort ? Something like "COL1 COL2 ASC, COL3 DESC"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx) requires 2 arguments if you want to sort. If you don't want to filter, use an empty string (`""`) as the first argument:

```
$array = $mydataset.Tables[0].Select("", "COL1 DESC, COL2 ASC")
```